# Length of non-null terminated char* array

Tags: c

The following method `slength` gives me an infinite loop (infinite "hello" statements). To find the length of a non-null terminated string, what do I need to look out for since there is no '\0'?.

```
int slength(const char *s) {
 printf("hello");
 int i = 0;
 while (s != NULL) {
    i++;
    s++;
    printf("hello");
 }
 return i;
}
```

This method seems to work but I feel there are too many checks to consider. Is there an easier way?

```
int silength(const char *s) {
    int i = 0;
     while( (*s>='a'&& *s<='z') || (*s>='A' && *s<='Z') || *s == ' ') {
    i++;
    s++;
    printf("hello\n");
 }
 return i;
}
```

Comment: `s` is a pointer an will only evaluate to `NULL` after wrapping around (as a 4 byte integer if you're on a small system, an 8 byte integer if you're really lucky - and prepared to wait for a while).

Comment: You have to be careful with non null terminated strings, either you should always terminate null or always have a size stored to prevent overflow.  You have a lot of risk with overflowing the bounds and exposing a vulnerability.

Comment: In the situation where I cannot null terminate the string, what check would I need to use in the loop?

Comment: Until and unless you don't have a delimiter, you can not break out of a loop. And working with non-NULL terminated char array is the worst design you can think of. It will very easily (without any effort) lead your process to the Undefined Behavior. Now, do you want to be one of those devs who don't know how their programs are going to behave?

Comment: A string in C is null-terminated. Otherwise it is not "a string".

Comment: In the situation where you cannot null terminate your string, have a char array of definite size and parse it char-by-char till you reach the boundary of array. The same, as you would do with an int array.

Comment: Okay. So if someone were to pass in const char array like "Hello world" as the argument, would mallocing another char array, adding in the characters and then a '\0' and then calculating the length of that be considered a good solution?

Comment: Yeah sure, that would be a good solution, but then again, you should have the length of passed array or else you would not know, how many bytes to allocate or copy to the allocated memory.

Comment: In general there are two ways to know the size of variable-length data structures: (1) store a count (which is how Pascal strings work), or (2) use a terminator (which is how C strings work).  But you have to use one or the other.  It sounds like you're trying to use some kind of a heuristic to determinal "normal" text string characters.  This will never work reliably. (1) What if there's punctuation in the string? (2) what if the string happens to be followed in memory by some "normal" text characters? (3) what if while looking you run off the end of memory and get a segmentation violation?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using standard C strings, and instead want to create your own type of string, you can't use common C methods to loop through your string. I suggest you make a data structure like

```
struct string {
    const char *text;
    int length;
};
```

that keeps track of the length of the string. Loop using the additional length information. You will probably have to create your own versions of many of the C standard library functions that handle strings, and conversion and factory functions would be useful.

Here are a couple of examples of string implementations in C that keep track of length:

[bstring](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/) by Paul Hsieh

[Text](https://github.com/kev009/cii/blob/master/include/text.h) from D. R. Hanson's C *Interfaces and Implementations*

Otherwise, just use null-terminated strings as this is the default in C. For example, string literals end with a null character.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `while(s!=NULL)` with `while(*s!=NULL)`.

Comment: I believe this will not work for a non-null-terminated array.